# I have a error in the webclient in c# when i use my website/ftp server and try to download a file like a image or text using the webclient?

Tags: c#

when I use my website/FTP server and try to download a file like an image or text using the WebClient
it downloads it fine but when I check my text file it has javascript code instead of the real text I..
here the code

```html
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    function toNumbers(d) {
        var e = [];
        d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
            e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
        });
        return e
    }

    function toHex() {
        for(var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
        return e.toLowerCase()
    }
    var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
        b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
        c = toNumbers("058937ea03ef3568d95787b3da25e784");
    document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
    location.href = " ??????/SysFiles/Changelog.Sysc?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support </noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show your C# code.

Comment: okay here is code

Comment: WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
            client1.DownloadFile("http://??????/SysFiles/Changelog.Sysc", "src/Update/Changelog.Sysc");
            client1.DownloadFile("???????/SysFiles/BGImage.jpg", "src/Images/BGImage.jpg");
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("src/Update/Changelog.Sysc"))
            {
                string News = file.ReadToEnd();
                richTextBox1.Text = News;
            }
            this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("src/Images/BGImage.jpg");
        }

Comment: FTP has a text mode and a binary mode.  I think you are using the text mode and not the binary mode.